# Summing regions of a matrix that do not over lap in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to sum a vector in groups of twenty the length of the vector is e.g. 7628. 
I can't figure out a way to output a vector with the sums of the sets of twenty or

```
ans = [sum(a(1:20) sum(a(21:30)....].
```

Comment: You're going to need to format this a little nicer. And add a little more code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 7600 is evenly divisible by 20, you can reshape and sum:

```
a = rand(7600,1);
sum(reshape(a,20,7600/20))
```

**EDIT** Addressing comment for non evenly divisible lengths

```
b    = 20;
sz   = size(a);

% Last elements to exclude
excl = mod(sz(1),b);

% Sum reshape and sum excluded separately
[sum(reshape(a(1:end-excl), b, fix(sz(1)/b))), sum(a(end-excl+1:end))]
```

Comment: I tried using reshape similar to what @oleg komarov has shown, but the number is not exactly divisible by 20 it is 7628. I've also tried an nlfilter, but that is a sliding scale not discrete chunks.

Comment: Next time mention it immediately that you have 7628.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just didn't have the number at hand, but I'll try the edited chunk seems like it should work Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`upfirdn` should also work well, with upscaling factor of `1`, impulse response of `ones(1,20)`, and decimation factor of `20`.

(Note: Requires Signal Processing Toolbox)